# Changing Git to another folder

Tags: git

I had already initialized git when I installed it with github but recently I initialized git using git init command to some other folder.
Will it affect my Git previous configuration?
If yes,how would i rollback my changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might help you by Visualization :

This command creates an empty Git repository -  .git directory created with subdirectories for objects, refs/heads, refs/tags and refs/remotes.

[If You want to revert the .git file or initialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UbXA.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`git init` initizializes a **git repository**, not Git itself. You can have as many repositories as you wish. If you have not started on the project yet, you can delete the folder and start over in a different folder if you wish. You can also move the folder anywhere you wish. You can switch between projects in different folders at will as well. So you can easily go to the first folder where you ran `git init` and do your work there.

As a beginner, I highly recommend that you read the first 3 chapters of [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) in order to understand the basic concepts.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer : No worries**, no interaction expected here. Just delete the first (unneeded) one and go with the new.

Edit : But don't miss Code-Apprentice insightful answer, he's a lot more explicit that I've been here.